# Cant update nor open project using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android Studio and copied the android projects folder from one machine to another.

when i tried to open the project folder from the second machine, most of the classes and methods are not recognised by Android studio as shown below in the image.

Also when i try to update eclipse I receive the error message shown below in the image and i do not know how to fix the it despite i am connected to the internet.

please let me know how to open the projects correctly and why i am not able to update Android studio despite i am connected to the internet

[image]

Comment: Q: Have you added dependency of  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' in gradle.build file ? Please check the internet connection works for studio or not by clicking update  option studio . Gradle build is online so it requires internet connection to download dependency.

Comment: @SuhasBachewar in your comment you said: "by clicking update option studio"..would u please tell me where is that?

Comment: option present in Help ->check_for_update.

Comment: @SuhasBachewar the dependencies are added and I enabled the online mode...but still the problem exists....does it has something to do with .idea folder?

Comment: Which version of studio you are using ? & OS Linux or Windows?

Comment: @SuhasBachewar actually i do not know..but i downloaded it since 2 months..and currently I uninstalled it and installing the most recent one...would that help soving the issue

Comment: chechk "Help->About " and tell me.

Comment: Go to File->Settings... and under HTTP Proxy select the No Proxy radio button, and click the Apply button

Comment: @SuhasBachewar now i am using Android studio 1.4 and the problem still exists..call back methods "onstart, onresume...." are not defined as well as the AppCompat class" and every thing is in the gradle

Comment: Do one thing proprely unistall Android studio and fresh install after restart or download 1.5 stable version.